# Why can we use the principal root in the polar form of complex numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

When solving algebra questions involving complex numbers, I often get solutions in the form $|z|e^{i n\theta} = r e^{i \varphi}$, and then have to consider all the solutions $\{r e^{i \frac{\varphi + 2k\pi}{n}} : k \in \{0, 1, ..., n-1\}\}$, taking $\sqrt[n]{x}$ to just be equal to its principal value (since $x = a^2 + b^2 > 0$ the associated positive real).

My question is, why can we just ignore the fact that there are several solutions to the root part as well, my intuition is that you have to consider the different complex solutions to the root as well, giving you more solutions (all the combinations between the choices of root and choices of angle.) I realise this leads to a kind of infinite regress where if you write the root in the same kind of polar form, you're going to find that issue continues to crop up.

Comment: Some questions to you that will help you rethink your question! How many solutions does a complex polynomial of degree $n$ has at maximum ? What is **the definition** of $\sqrt[n]{x}$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, it has at most $n$ solutions per the fundamental theorem of algebra, which confirms that you can indeed ignore the different roots, but I'm not sure why still. The definition of $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is a number which equals $x$ when raised to the $n$th power, so you can ignore which you pick if you go on to do this, but I don't see that in this process? Sorry if it's obvious, I've managed to confuse myself quite well here.

Comment: You "often" get solutions in the form $|z|e^{i n\theta} = \sqrt[n]{x} e^{i \varphi}$, with an $n$th power on the left **and** an $n$th root on the right in the same equation? Really? Can you show an example of this from start to finish?

Comment: Let me put this another way. I cannot see any useful relationship between the set $\{\sqrt[n]{x} e^{i \frac{\varphi + 2k\pi}{n}} : k \in \{0, 1, ..., n-1\}\}$ and the equation $|z|e^{i n\theta} = \sqrt[n]{x} e^{i \varphi}.$ The set **does** make sense as a solution set for some problems, so I suspect you have written the equation incorrectly. I'm sure there is a simple explanation for how the set is a solution for the equation from which it originally came, but that explanation cannot be written unless we have the correct equation to start from. I recommend you edit the question to fix this.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to repair the formulas in the question. I think you're having trouble understanding the logic behind the method (why is the principal root enough?) because you're confused about how the symbols in the problem and solution actually relate to each other. A good starting point for understanding is to write down a self-consistent example of what the symbols **are**. I suggest looking in your textbook or notes for a solved problem of this kind, and copy the problem statement and its solution into the question exactly as originally written.

Answer (score 2):

It's because primitive roots can be algebraically indistinguishable. A simple example is the solutions to $z^4=1$ which are $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$. Here $i$ and $-i$ are both primitive roots. Say I define $j=-i$. Then the solution set is $\{1,-1,j,-j\}$ which looks very familiar. It has all the same structure despite the fact we relabeled them.

This same idea holds in generality. If we consider solutions to $z^5=1$ since $z$ is prime we have four primitive roots and they all obey the same algebraic relations. It doesn't matter which one I pick with regards to their algebraic structure. So if we want to call one out as exceptional we have to look for a property that isn't algebraic. Even then, if the roots are complex the conjugate map $a+bi \rightarrow a-bi$ will give you a second algebraically indistinguishable choice.

This is important when you're working on the unit circle in the complex plane. As you know form trigonometry the unit circle is incredibly important and [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) are all on the unit circle. In fact the $n$-th roots will form a regular $n$-gon so there is a strong geometric connection as well. All of that comes *after* we pick $i$ or $-i$ as above, because it's essentially choice of orientation. We call $i$ the one that goes up and $-i$ the one that goes down but we could have gone the other way via conjugation.

When we choose a certain algebraic value due to geometry, say the one with the smallest angle counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis, the location of that root is a consequence of our original choice. The roots don't come equipped with their own geometry a priori, it's something we impose on it after the fact because it's so useful.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if I am interpreting your question correctly, so unclear if
this response is on point.  Please advise if my interpretation is wrong.

For $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}, ~k \in \{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}, ~$
let $~\xi_{n,k}~$ denote $~e^{i2k\pi/n}.~$

So $~\xi_{n,k}~$ represents
the $~n~$ distinct roots of $~z^n = 1.~$

For $~x \in \Bbb{R^+}, ~\theta \in \Bbb{R},~$
suppose that you want to compute
$~\displaystyle \left[ ~xe^{i\theta} ~\right] ^{1/n}.~$

Further, suppose that 
$~-\pi < \theta \leq \pi,~$ and that $~\alpha = \theta/n.$

Also, suppose that $~s~$ is the unique positive real number such that
$~s^n = x.~$

So, if I have interpreted your question correctly, you want to know
why you can express the $~n~$ roots as $~\displaystyle s \times \left[ ~e^{i\alpha} \times \xi_{n,k} ~\right] ~? $

You do not **also** need to attempt to apply the
$~\xi_{n,k}~$ factors directly to the factor of $~s.~$

That is, the $~\xi_{n,k}~$ factors are already being applied to the
$~e^{i\alpha}~$ factor.  That is sufficient to represent all $~n~$ distinct roots of $~\displaystyle \left[ ~xe^{i\theta} ~\right] ^{1/n}.~$

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try to deduce here what the actual question is.

There are multiple ways one might arrive at the solution set
$$
\{\sqrt[n]{x} e^{i (\varphi + 2k\pi)/n} : k \in \{0, 1, ..., n-1\}\},
$$
but the most obvious application is when we have a complex number $z$
expressed in a "polar" form, in particular
$$
z = x e^{i\varphi},
$$
and when the question is, "What are all the $n$th roots of $z$?"

Whenever we have a polar form of a complex number $z$, it is always a non-negative real number (the number $\lvert z\rvert$, called the modulus or magnitude of $z$) multiplied by $e$ raised to a pure imaginary power.
That is, in the example above, $x$ and $\varphi$ are both real numbers.

To confirm that $\sqrt[n]{x} e^{i(\varphi + 2k\pi)/n}$ is an $n$th root of
$x e^{i\varphi}$ for any integer $k,$ just take the $n$th power:
\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt[n]{x} e^{i(\varphi + 2k\pi)/n}\right)^n
&= \left(\sqrt[n]{x}\right)^n \left(e^{i (\varphi + 2k\pi)/n}\right)^n \\
&= x\left(e^{i(\varphi + 2k\pi)/n}\right)^n && \text{$x$ is real and $x\geq 0$} \\
&= x e^{n(i(\varphi + 2k\pi)/n)} && (z^a)^b = z^{ab} = z^{ba} \\
&= x e^{i(\varphi + 2k\pi)}  \\
&= x e^{i\varphi} e^{i2k\pi} && z^{a+b} = z^a z^b \\
&= x e^{i\varphi}  && e^{i2k\pi} = 1 \ \text{when $k$ is an integer} \\
\end{align}

Moreover, $\sqrt[n]{x} e^{i(\varphi + 2k\pi)/n}
 = \left(\sqrt[n]{x} e^{i\varphi}\right) e^{i2k\pi/n}$,
and for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n$ the number $e^{i2k\pi/n}$ is plotted at $n$ equally spaced points on the unit circle in the Argand plane.
Multiplying each of these points by the same value $\sqrt[n]{x} e^{i\varphi}$
gives us $n$ different points in the Argand plane,
that is, these are all $n$ of the $n$th roots of $x e^{i\varphi}.$

The main reason why we **want** to choose the principal $n$th root of $x$ rather than any of the $n - 1$ other $n$th roots is so that the answer (as well as the question) puts the numbers in polar form, which requires that
$e^{i(\varphi + 2k\pi)/n}$ be multiplied by a non-negative real number.
The reason we **can** choose the principal $n$th root is that it lets us find all $n$ of the $n$th roots.

We cannot find any more of the answers by taking a different $n$th root of $x$, because we've already found all of them.

---

If you don't care about whether you have the answer in an actual polar form or not, you *could* use any of the $n$th roots of $x$. Any single root of $x$ will get you all the roots of $z = x e^{i\varphi}$.

For example, suppose you want to find the cube roots of
$5 e^{i\pi/3}.$
Let $x = 5$ and $\varphi = \frac\pi3,$ and then the cube roots are
$\sqrt[n]{x} e^{i(\varphi + 2k\pi)/n} = \sqrt[3]{5} e^{i(\pi/9 + 2k\pi/3)}$
for $k = 0, 1, 2$; that is, the three cube roots are
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{5} e^{i(\pi/9 + 2(0)\pi/3)} &= \sqrt[3]{5} e^{i\pi/9}, \\
\sqrt[3]{5} e^{i(\pi/9 + 2(1)\pi/3)} &= \sqrt[3]{5} e^{i7\pi/9}, \\
\sqrt[3]{5} e^{i(\pi/9 + 2(2)\pi/3)} &= \sqrt[3]{5} e^{i13\pi/9}
= \sqrt[3]{5} e^{-i5\pi/9}.
\end{align}

Now suppose that instead of the principal root $\sqrt[n]{5}$
you used one of the other complex cube roots of $5$,
for example $\sqrt[3]{5} e^{i2\pi/3}.$
Substituting this in place of $\sqrt[3]{5}$ for $k = 0, 1, 2,$ you would get
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{5} e^{i2\pi/3} e^{i(\pi/9 + 2(0)\pi/3)} &= \sqrt[3]{5} e^{i7\pi/9}, \\
\sqrt[3]{5} e^{i2\pi/3} e^{i(\pi/9 + 2(1)\pi/3)}
 &= \sqrt[3]{5} e^{i13\pi/9} = \sqrt[3]{5} e^{-i5\pi/9}, \\
\sqrt[3]{5} e^{i2\pi/3} e^{i(\pi/9 + 2(2)\pi/3)}
 &= \sqrt[3]{5} e^{i19\pi/9} = \sqrt[3]{5} e^{i\pi/9}.
\end{align}

So you get exactly the same three roots; the only difference is that each root is produced by a different value of $k$ than it was when you used the principal cube root of $5$.

It works like this for any other $n$th root; using any of the other cube roots of $\lvert z\rvert$ finds the same $n$ roots, merely in a different sequence for $k = 0,1,2.$